# How to add others libraries such as Zenpen to WYSIWYG profiles?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I would like to use an editor for Drupal like [Zenpen](http://www.zenpen.io/). Is it possible to add that library (Zenpen) to WYSIWYG profiles?

Comment: http://blog.valderama.net/add-ckeditor-plugin-your-wysiwyg-profile-0 You may add the plugin in using an additional function. Please find the link above.

Comment: Thanks, but this is to install Ckeditor, and I would like to install Zenpen. Do you know a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write a WYSIWYG module plugin. [Here is an example module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ueditor) you could follow.

[Here is a simple](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/wysiwyg/tree/editors/jwysiwyg.inc) `.inc` from the WYSIWYG module itself. Wrap your Zenpen one in a module like Ueditor (above) and you're done.